# Guide to implementing password recovery with dynamic URL sent to email over atlassian crowd with spring security

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, password-recovery, atlassian-crowd, authentication-flows

I am trying to use crowd's built-in forgot password functionality over my app with spring security.But for [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/11981904/how-can-i-redirect-user-to-specific-url-after-users-password-change) issue I guess I need have my own implementations. I also come accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219917/guide-to-implementing-spring-security-password-recovery-with-dynamic-url-sent-to) discussion which says I can avoid all complexities with dynamic auto-expiring links emails+database stuffs using [authentication-flows](https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows). Has anyone done it before? What would be the best path forward? Can you share your experience about these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [authentication-flows](/questions/tagged/authentication-flows) module can integrate with different types of DBs. Currently, I have implemented connections to SQL server as well as GAE ([gae-datastore](/questions/tagged/gae-datastore)).

AFAI understand, you need your own implementation, one that can invoke (REST) calls to Atlassian DB. So there is a need to research what is the API of Atlassian, and what are their capabilities of 'create account', 'forgot password', 'change password' and so on, and of course what is their implementation (do they send emails to users etc).

Note that the [authentication-flows](/questions/tagged/authentication-flows) delegates the call to the relevant implementation, for example create-account, and it expects the implementation nothing but creating the entry in the DB. So if Atlassian implementation involves with sending e-mails to users upon account-creation, the user will get 2 email: one from Atlassian and the 2nd from auth-flows, and it will be problematic.

**EDIT**:

After reading [CROWD's REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/Crowd+REST+APIs) and [Resources](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/Crowd+REST+Resources), is looks doable!

Comment: Thanks OhadR! Gotta try it.

Comment: let me know how it is going... and if you implement the connection to Atlassian, we can add it to GitHub