# Authentication-Flows: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, authentication-flows

I'm refer to project of OhadR, He is using Spring security to login and set new password by email.
this link:

```
Authentication-Flows: https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows
```

I have finished some steps as:

```
1. create account
2. confirm account by email
3. login sucess
4. change or set new password (this step happened exception)
```

But when I input new password and confirm new password, I received an exception following as:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1] with root cause
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at com.ohadR.web.crypto.service.CryptoService.getDecodedStringFromEncodedBased64String(CryptoService.java:244)
at com.ohadR.web.crypto.service.CryptoService.extractStringAndDate(CryptoService.java:107)
at com.ohadR.web.auth_flows.core.AuthenticationFlowsProcessorImpl.handleSetNewPassword(AuthenticationFlowsProcessorImpl.java:279)
at com.ohadR.web.auth_flows.web.UserActionController.setNewPassword(UserActionController.java:239)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
```

This is scope code cause exception:

```
@Override
public String handleSetNewPassword( 
        String encUserAndTimestamp,
        String password,
        String retypedPassword) throws AuthenticationFlowsException
{
    validateRetypedPassword(password, retypedPassword);

    ImmutablePair<Date, String> stringAndDate =
    cryptoService.extractStringAndDate( encUserAndTimestamp );

    validateExpiration(stringAndDate.getLeft());

    String email = stringAndDate.getRight();

    //after validations, make the work: validate password constraints, and update DB:

    //validate the input:
    AuthenticationPolicy settings = getAuthenticationSettings();

    validatePassword(password, settings);



    String encodedPassword = encodeString(email, password);

    // go to the DB and: (1) update the password, and (2) activate the account:
    setPassword(email, encodedPassword);

    return email;
}
```

Set values to debug: (**Updated**)
[image]

(**Updated**)

get and set value when debug:
value of link in email:

```
http://localhost:9999/rp?uts=ap0wGvPL56FiYbMshHLe5Yh5PWEkz/kWEbJA32uJPSxw
```

When click this link, it will redirect to URL(set new password screen):

```
http://localhost:9999/login/setNewPassword.jsp?enc=ap0wGvPL56FiYbMshHLe5Yh5PWEkz/kWEbJA32uJPSxw
```

and then input value in encUserAndTimestamp parameter in debug

finally, I received an message error:

```
Failed to decrypt URL content http://localhost:9999/login/setNewPassword.jsp?enc=ap0wGvPL56FiYbMshHLe5Yh5PWEkz/kWEbJA32uJPSxw
```

It seem my URL is wrong !!

How to fix this exception, thank so much!

Comment: Hi @OhadR: I have set value in debug and it apprear, i have updated picture..

Comment: i still cant see the value of encUserAndTimestamp ...

Comment: Yes value of encUserAndTimestamp was blank or null, how to get value of encUserAndTimestamp ?

Comment: I have tried get value of encUserAndTimestamp, but can't, seem this is a bug :(

Comment: Hi @OhadR: I have updated my result as above

Comment: tell me if this helps: https://youtu.be/4yDXHDjFcr0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; indeed it is a bug (since 2014...)

https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows/issues/13

However though, I've just try to reproduce it (forgot-password flow), and it works fine! [Here is a link to YouTube](http://youtu.be/4yDXHDjFcr0), so you can see exactly what I did...

Comment: Hi @OhadR: Im back because I lost my password before, I'm following your link on youtube

Comment: everything is good, and it will great if you improve more welcome screen and logout :)